# How to define startPoint endPoint for horizontal line

Tags: ios

I want to draw a horizontal line with a gradient at loc 550.

```
CGFloat colors[6] = { 
    138.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f,
    162.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f,
    206.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f};
CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.05f, 0.45f, 0.95f };
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, 3);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGPoint endPoint   = CGPointMake(0, 550);

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
 CGContextSaveGState(context);
 CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 550, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1));
 CGContextClip(context);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient (context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

No line is drawn in this code and the Xcode gives me this error:

```
            CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: Your question is mislabeled, then.  Your problem is that you have an invalid `CGContextRef`.  Where are you placing this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place this code in your `drawRect:` method of a `UIView` object to make sure a current `context` exists.  Otherwise you need to use `UIGraphicsPushContext` to get a current `context`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`:

> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its
>   drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack,
>   making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your
>   drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack
>   manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function.
>
> You should call this function from the main thread of your application
>   only.